# Passing Dynamic Range:Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, range

I'm trying to write a custom function that will count and return the number of cells that contain information on a singular column. I'm using a range of A(x):Z(x) and I can't seem to dynamically pass these so I can get a user defined range everytime.

**Edit: Current Error I'm receiving right now says: Missing ) after argument list. (line 10, file "Number Of Updates")**

So far I have this....

```
function updateNum(row1,col1,row2,col2)
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName("report status");
 var r = s.getActiveRange(row1+col1:row2+col2); <---Line with error
 return (range.length-2)/2
}
```

any suggestions on how I could make this pass the range?

thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

change the line for:

```
var r= s.getRange(row1, col1, row2-row1+1, col2-col1+1);
```

but that won't solve your problems has the line just behind is a non sense. "range" is not declared. I don't see where you want to go exactly. please write some pseudocode.

If what you want is to count the number of cells that got informations in it, just use the spreadsheet native function

```
counta()
```

Comment: I thought about using Counta() but I wasn't quite sure how to execute it on a column. Could you explain how I would go about doing that?

Comment: write in a cell =counta(A2:A) to count all the non blank cell in the column A starting at the cell A2 (exluding A1) this formula shouldn't be wrote in a cell from the column A.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see if I can iterate what I'm trying to do. Thanks a bunch for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with custom functions because they are deterministic. That is, they will return the same result given the same input.
In your case even if you fix the bugs you are still not passing the actual input just its range limits. Thus if the data inside the range changes you still pass the same input limits thus will return the previous cached result.
There are ways arround that like passing an extra parameter that always changes like 'now()'but that has performance problems as it will recalculate constantly.